# Subgroups of a Galois Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

I've just started studying Galois Theory and I'm having a litte trouble with the following exercise:

Find all the subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}\big(X^4-X^2 -2\ ;\mathbb{Q}\big)$. Which of the subgroups are normal?

I appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having? Did you calculate the group? Are you finding it hard to find subgroups? Are you having trouble finding those that are normal...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve for the roots of $Y^2-Y-2$ which are $2$ and $-1$, so that the roots of your polynomial are $\pm \sqrt 2$ and $\pm i$. Then you're trying to find the Galois group of $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 2)/\mathbb Q$, which is $C_2\times C_2$. Since this is abelian, all subgroups are normal.